# Multithreading Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Недавно начал изучать java по книге Г.Шилдта "Java 8". Дошел до Fork/Join и появились несколько вопросов по многопоточности. Отдельно вроде все понятно, но картина в целом пока вырисовывается смутно. Так как изучал по книге - первое с чем пришлось столкнуться - это Thread, Runnable, synchronized и т.д. Потом дошел до concurrent библиотеки и появились вопросы. Насколько я сейчас понимаю, классы  concurrent  - это просто более абстрактная обертка для класса Thread и его методов? Что интерфейс Lock внутри себя использует те же synchronized, wait(), notify() и т.д.? А классы Fork/Join используют внутри себя классы concurrent? Где то слышал, что ForkJoinPool использует ThreadPoolExecutor, но информация противоречивая.

Comment: Задавайте по 1 вопросу в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Так как изучал по книге - первое с чем пришлось столкнуться - это Thread, Runnable, synchronized и т.д. Потом дошел до concurrent библиотеки и появились вопросы. Насколько я сейчас понимаю, классы concurrent - это просто более абстрактная обертка для класса Thread и его методов? Что интерфейс Lock внутри себя использует те же synchronized, wait(), notify() и т.д.?

Позволю немного придраться - сам интерфейс, конечно, внутри себя ничего не использует. В целом, да, существует некоторое количество примитивов, предоставляемых ОС и инструкциями процессора, на основе которых строятся более сложные конструкции. Как правило, все упирается в те или иные native методы Thread, Object и такого странного класса, как Unsafe (это справедливо только для восьмерки, как обстоит дело в готовящейся девятке - не знаю), а также в различные модификаторы методов и полей (synchronized, volatile). В принципе, исходный код rt.jar (той самой стандартной библиотеки с java.util, java.lang, java.time и другими пакетами) вполне себе доступен и во многих дистрибутивах линукс доступен просто как пакет со стандартным именем и суффиксом `-sources`. Так или иначе вы можете заполучить файл src.zip, в котором будет доступен весь исходный код с комментариями, и который автоматом подхватывается IDEA, и, скорее всего, другими IDE. В этих исходниках можно увидеть, как реализованы все часто используемые классы, и, в лучшем случае, подробные объяснения в комментариях.

> Соответственно, конструкции Fork/Join используют внутри классы concurrent? То есть ForkJoinPool.execute() неявно использует ExecutorService, который, в свою очередь, создает Thread'ы?
>
> Есть ли разница в хардварной реализации многопоточности между использованием стандартных конструкций на Thread/Runnable и Fork/Join?

Нет, из-за особенностей реализации (в т.ч. необходимости уменьшения издержек холостого хода при отсутствии работы) ForkJoinPool управляет аналогичной инфраструктурой самостоятельно, но использует обычные Thread. Чуть подробнее можно прочитать в [соответствующей работе](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf) автора.

> То есть, если я запущу второй Thread на двухядерном процессоре, то JVM запустит его на втором ядре?

JVM (по крайней мере, большая часть реализаций), не управляет тем, где именно будет выполняться поток, эта работа отдается ОС.

> И если я запущу new ForkJoinPool(8) на двухядерном процессоре с четырьмя тредами, то 4 потока из 8-и реализуются квантированием времени?

Одновременно будет выполняться до двух потоков, управлять распределением процессорного времени меду потоками будет ОС.

> Могу ли я распараллелить потоки на двухядерном процессоре так, чтобы все потоки исполнялись на одном ядре? Как это указать явно?

Изнутри JVM - нет, однако операционная система может иметь инструменты для ограничения ядер, на которых может запускаться процесс.